# Enable all warnings in Flake8?

Tags: python, pep8, tox, flake8

I am using `flake8` (from `tox` or from `Makefile`). It basically gave me warnings about whitespaces and I got my codebase clean, so I though.
I was then surprised that `Pycharm` IDE displayed me a ton of style warnings, which `flake8` hadn't complained about yet. These are naming styles and more interesting things like class member initialization outside of `__init__`. Pycharm is also using only Pep8 checks, to my understanding.

How can I get `flake8` to be extremely strict? I tried `strict=1` in the `tox.ini`, or `ignore=`, but nothing got me more than whitespace warnings.

Comment: pycharm uses other things (not flake8) to do its checks -- you can add plugins to flake8 to get more types of checks

Comment: Pycharm uses (among others) ``Pep8`` checks. I believe these are the once I am missing in ``flake8``. My question should have been more specific about Pep8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anthony said in the comments, you can add plugins to flake8 in order to incorporate different static code checks - see the [instructions](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/using-plugins.html) from `flake8` for full details on how to do this.

If the plugin is in PyPi, you can simply install using `pip` and it should be good to go:

```
pip install <plugin-name>
```

Some examples of useful plugins, extracted from this [blog post](https://julien.danjou.info/the-best-flake8-extensions/), are `flake8-import-order`, which will check that your `import`s are ordered correctly and `flake8-builtins`, which checks that you are not hiding any builtin variables by re-defining them.